# Dynamically creating instance names?

Tags: java

Consider the following which doesn't work.   What should be done to make it work.  I would like to dynamically create instances of song, s1, s2, s3, etc.  I realize there are no methods for Object in Song, but I cannot assign s1, s2, s3 to song either.

```
int i;
String s;

for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
{
    //Stuff to get song info omitted. 

    Object thisSong = s + Integer.toString(i);//append 1 to s

    thisSong = new Song(title, artist, playTime, fileName);//create new object 

    System.out.println(thisSong.getTitle());// Error here.  getTitle() is undefined. 
}
```

//Song Class below...

```
public class Song
{
private String title;
private String artist;
private int playTime; // in seconds
private String fileName;

public Song(String title, String artist, int playTime, String fileName)
{
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.playTime = playTime;
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public String getArtist()
{
    return artist;
}

public int getPlayTime()
{
    return playTime;
}

public String getFileName()
{
    return fileName;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return  String.format("%-20s %-20s %-25s %10s",title, artist, fileName, playTime);
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please add the `Song` source to your question.

Comment: `thisSong` is a `String` not `Song`, hence the method undefined error

Comment: Reference `thisSong` is of type `Object` which doesn't have `getTitle` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Other answer suggests casting, but you will get a `ClassCastException` if you try to do `Song song = (Song)thisSong;` because what you are storing in `thisSong` is not a `Song` object, it is a `String`.

Because you are trying to call  `getTitle` I believe you want to generate titles for your songs. So maybe try something like this:

```
for (int i=0, i < 4, i++){ 

   String title = s + i; // no need to use Integer.toString() because using '+' with a String(s) turns i into a String too
   Song mySong = new Song(title, artist, playTime, fileName);

   System.out.print( mySong.getTitle() );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable ***thisSong*** has Object type but Object type doesn't have getTitle() method.
All what you need just cast ***thisSong*** to Song type like this:

```
Song song = (Song)thisSong;
song.getTitle();
```

or

```
((Song)thisSong).getTitle();
```